# scala mockito error `value thenReturn is not a member of Nothing`

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, actor

```
  val users = List(User(name = "A"))
  val userRepoMock = mock[UserRepo]

  "GET /users" should {
    "return the users" in {
      when(userRepoMock.get()).thenReturn(Future.successful(Good(users)))
```

When I run the test, it doesn't compile

```
   value thenReturn is not a member of Nothing
   [error]      L55:      
   when(userRepoMock.get()).thenReturn(Future.successful(Good(users)))
   [error]      L55:
```

Could anyone can help me to fix this issue, please?
Thanks in advance

Here is a definition of UserRepo

```
trait UserRepo {
  def get(): Future[List[User]]
}

object UserRepo {

  class ActorImpl @Inject()(actor: UserSyncActor.Ref) extends UserRepo {
    override def get(): Future[List[User]] = {
      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 10.seconds
      actor.ref.ask(UserSyncActor.GetUsers).mapTo[List[User]]
    }
  }
}
```

I also linked the UserRepo with its ActorImpl in a module

```
class ActorsModule extends AbstractModule {
  ...

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val _ = bind(classOf[UserRepo]).to(classOf[UserRepo.ActorImpl])
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this is compiling.
Future[Good[List[User]]] is not the same type as Future[List[User]]].

You should get a compilation error when trying to write this mock.

Maybe if you put the whole test code, it would be easier to see what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue recently, for me the issue was that what I was returning inside the `thenReturn()` was a different type to what the function I was mocking should return.

In your case I'd double check that `Future.successful(Good(users))` is `Future[List[User]]` but this error message is pretty vague and unhelpful so could be something else